# How do I correct this mismapped stylus button?

Tags: touchscreen, udev, remapping, stylus, keycodes

I'm running Kubuntu 15.10 on an HP Spectre x360, which has a non-Wacom active digitizer built into the display. I'm using a two-button stylus with this, but the second button doesn't work. I couldn't get `xinput` to show any state change when the button is pressed; it seems X can't see it at all. `evtest` does see an event, but it reports the button as `BTN_TOOL_RUBBER` instead of the appropriate `BTN_STYLUS2`:

```
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x4f3 product 0x2073 version 0x110
Input device name: "ELAN Touchscreen Pen"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 256 (BTN_0)
    Event code 320 (BTN_TOOL_PEN)
    Event code 321 (BTN_TOOL_RUBBER)
    Event code 330 (BTN_TOUCH)
    Event code 331 (BTN_STYLUS)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value  23080
      Min        0
      Max    32256
      Resolution     110
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value  10408
      Min        0
      Max    17920
      Resolution     108
    Event code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max      255
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
Event: time 1453608432.242049, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 321 (BTN_TOOL_RUBBER), value 1
Event: time 1453608432.242049, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

The stylus has no eraser tip. `input-kbd` gives me the scancodes and shows the same issue:

```
/dev/input/event8
   bustype : BUS_USB
   vendor  : 0x4f3
   product : 0x2073
   version : 272
   name    : "ELAN Touchscreen Pen"
   phys    : "usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0"
   uniq    : ""
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY EV_ABS EV_MSC

map: 15 keys, size: 294/320
0xd0032 = 320  # BTN_TOOL_PEN
0xd0042 = 330  # BTN_TOUCH
0xd0044 = 331  # BTN_STYLUS
0xd003c = 321  # BTN_TOOL_RUBBER
0xd0045 = 256  # BTN_0
0xd0042 = 330  # BTN_TOUCH
0xd0042 = 330  # BTN_TOUCH
0xd0042 = 330  # BTN_TOUCH
0xd0042 = 330  # BTN_TOUCH
0xd0042 = 330  # BTN_TOUCH
0xd0042 = 330  # BTN_TOUCH
0xd0042 = 330  # BTN_TOUCH
0xd0042 = 330  # BTN_TOUCH
0xd0042 = 330  # BTN_TOUCH
0xd0042 = 330  # BTN_TOUCH
```

Trying to use `input-kbd` to assign a new map gives a "scancode out of range" error. The straightforward `setkeycodes d003c 332` also does not work (USB keyboard bug).

Update: I've tried fixing this through udev by adding a custom hwdb file to /etc/udev/hwdb.d, but it doesn't seem to be having any effect.

```
$ cat /etc/udev/hwdb.d/61-touchscreen-quirks.hwdb 
evdev:input:b0003v04f3p2073e0110*   # Matches ELAN Touchscreen devices
 KEYBOARD_KEY_d003c=14c             # Reassigns scancode from BTN_TOOL_RUBBER to BTN_STYLUS2

$ sudo udevadm --debug hwdb --update
calling: hwdb
reading file '/lib/udev/hwdb.d/20-OUI.hwdb'
reading file '/lib/udev/hwdb.d/20-acpi-vendor.hwdb'
reading file '/lib/udev/hwdb.d/20-bluetooth-vendor-product.hwdb'
reading file '/lib/udev/hwdb.d/20-libgphoto2-6.hwdb'
reading file '/lib/udev/hwdb.d/20-net-ifname.hwdb'
reading file '/lib/udev/hwdb.d/20-pci-classes.hwdb'
reading file '/lib/udev/hwdb.d/20-pci-vendor-model.hwdb'
reading file '/lib/udev/hwdb.d/20-sdio-classes.hwdb'
reading file '/lib/udev/hwdb.d/20-sdio-vendor-model.hwdb'
reading file '/lib/udev/hwdb.d/20-usb-classes.hwdb'
reading file '/lib/udev/hwdb.d/20-usb-media-players.hwdb'
reading file '/lib/udev/hwdb.d/20-usb-vendor-model.hwdb'
reading file '/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-evdev.hwdb'
reading file '/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb'
reading file '/etc/udev/hwdb.d/61-touchscreen-quirks.hwdb'
reading file '/lib/udev/hwdb.d/69-libmtp.hwdb'
reading file '/lib/udev/hwdb.d/70-mouse.hwdb'
reading file '/lib/udev/hwdb.d/70-pointingstick.hwdb'
=== trie in-memory ===
nodes:             3899920 bytes (   97498)
children arrays:   1559952 bytes (   97497)
values arrays:     1241904 bytes (   77619)
strings:           1721567 bytes
strings incoming:  4005992 bytes (  240722)
strings dedup'ed:  2347672 bytes (  177476)
=== trie on-disk ===
size:              6863455 bytes
header:                 80 bytes
nodes:             2339952 bytes (   97498)
child pointers:    1559952 bytes (   97497)
value pointers:    1241904 bytes (   77619)
string store:      1721567 bytes
strings start:     5141888

$ sudo udevadm -d control --reload
calling: control

$ sudo udevadm -d trigger /dev/input/event*
calling: trigger

$ sudo udevadm info -q all -p /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:04F3:2073.0004/input/input9
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:04F3:2073.0004/input/input9
E: ABS=1000003
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:04F3:2073.0004/input/input9
E: EV=1b
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_FOR_SEAT=input-pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_4_1_0
E: ID_INPUT=1
E: ID_INPUT_TABLET=1
E: ID_MODEL=Touchscreen
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Touchscreen
E: ID_MODEL_ID=2073
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_4_1_0
E: ID_REVISION=5107
E: ID_SERIAL=ELAN_Touchscreen
E: ID_TYPE=hid
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030000:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_VENDOR=ELAN
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=ELAN
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=04f3
E: KEY=c03 1 0 0 0 0
E: MODALIAS=input:b0003v04F3p2073e0110-e0,1,3,4,k100,140,141,14A,14B,ra0,1,18,m4,lsfw
E: MSC=10
E: NAME="ELAN Touchscreen Pen"
E: PHYS="usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0"
E: PRODUCT=3/4f3/2073/110
E: PROP=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=input
E: TAGS=:seat:
E: UNIQ=""
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=4595650
```

What did I do wrong here, or alternatively, what is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to remap the scancode to `BTN_STYLUS2` using `ir-keytable`. The command was:

```
sudo ir-keytable --device /dev/input/event8 --set-key 0xd003c=BTN_STYLUS2
```

HOWEVER, while I could see that the scancode had been successfully rebound, the button remained dead. `evtest` no longer reported any event when the button was pressed.

Before this, there was no `MSC_SCAN` event reported by `evtest` when that button was pressed, though there were scancodes reported for the other button and also the pen touch. This didn't strike me as more than an odd quirk at the time, but now it seems like the button really does generate no scancode. How did `evtest` report a keycode event at all, then? Beats me, and at this point I'm chalking it up to a kernel bug.

In the end, I just kludged together a bash script to watch `evtest` for `BTN_TOOL_RUBBER` events and simulate a right-click with `xdotool`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Find the input device number.
devicename="ELAN Touchscreen Pen"
numevents=$(ls /dev/input | grep -c event*)
for ((devnr=0;devnr<$numevents;devnr++)); do
    input-kbd $devnr | grep -q "$devicename"
    if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
        break
    fi
done

# Listen for BTN_TOOL_RUBBER events.
evtest /dev/input/event$devnr | while read line; do
for value in {0..1}; do
    echo $line | grep -q "type 1 (EV_KEY), code 321 (BTN_TOOL_RUBBER), value $value"
    if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
        case $value in
            0)  xdotool mouseup 3   ;;
            1)  xdotool mousedown 3 ;;
        esac
    fi
done
done
```

This gives me essentially the basic functionality I wanted anyways. It's not perfect: the mouseup event only happens once the pen leaves proximity, not when the button is released (this is when the `BTN_TOOL_RUBBER` key-up event is reported in `evtest`), but it works well enough that I'm not going to try debugging the kernel.

Comment: +1 for an excellent recovery (read "hack") on what does look like a bug indeed (but perhaps  not a kernel bug ?) .  I would mark yr own answer as the good answer for others to notice it. Congrats on being so clear, and concise in both yr pbm statement and the solution you provide. Real nice.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems with my Surface Pro 3 and solved it this way:

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=312005&p=1762496#p1762496

After the device is listed in `xsetwacom list device`, you can remap the buttons with `xsetwacom` easy.

Comment: Bringing over the relevant details will be helpful if/when that link goes bad.

Comment: Hello and welcome on Ask Ubuntu! Link only answers are discouraged as they might become obsolete if the link expires in future. May I suggest you to add some details in your post ?

Answer (score -1):

This one is a year old, but I wanted to say that your `hwdb` file is almost correct. But:

1. The right hand side has to be in decimal, not hex, so use `332` not `14c`.
2. The left hand side comes from `evtest` not `input-kbd` (don't ask because I don't really know). Specifically it's from the `value` field in the `MSC_SCAN` line IMMEDIATELY preceding the `BTN_TOOL_RUBBER` (or whatever the mismapped key is) event.

In my case I had:

```
type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value d0045
```

So my complete `hwdb` file is:

```
evdev:input:b0003v04F3p21D0*
  KEYBOARD_KEY_d0045=332
```

1. `sudo udevadm hwdb --update`
2. `sudo udevadm trigger /dev/input/event*`
3. Reboot.

Comment: I can't find any evidence that "The right hand side has to be in decimal" although theres a great deal to the contrary. Can you cite a reputable source? Perhaps reviewing `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb` or similar would bring you to the same conclusion that I reached.