# Remap BTN_STYLUS event to standard keyboard key?

Tags: keyboard, udev, input-devices, input, remapping

I'm attemping to use a VEIKK graphics tablet in Kubuntu 19.10. I've got a satisfactory setup so far, but the only thing remaining is remapping the stylus buttons. I feel like I have all the ingredients to do so, but can't figure out how to put it all together.

`evtest` identifies the input in question:

```
/dev/input/event3:  VEIKK S640 Pen
```

Running `evtest` on this input reports:

```
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x2feb product 0x1 version 0x100
Input device name: "VEIKK S640 Pen"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 330 (BTN_TOUCH)
    Event code 331 (BTN_STYLUS)
    Event code 332 (BTN_STYLUS2)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value  15580
      Min        0
      Max    98304
      Resolution       1
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value  13040
      Min        0
      Max    32768
      Resolution       1
    Event code 24 (ABS_PRESSURE)
      Value   1670
      Min        0
      Max     8192
```

And indeed, when pressing the stylus button, I see

```
Event: time 1586123903.365325, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 331 (BTN_STYLUS), value 1
```

followed later by

```
Event: time 1586123903.499328, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 331 (BTN_STYLUS), value 0
```

What I would like to do is simply *replace* these generated events with different events, say

```
type 1 (EV_KEY), code 30 (KEY_A), value 1
```

for the first and similarly for the second, so that pressing the stylus button is the same as pressing the `a` key down (and up) on the keyboard.

There are several closely related questions on this site, [this being probably the closest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724891/how-do-i-correct-this-mismapped-stylus-button), but the proposed solutions and final solution are quite kludgy. I've also prototyped writing a python-evdev script to "filter" these events into something, but that comes with its own problems.

So, is there any standard way to accomplish this using `udev`?

Comment: It's Kubuntu 19.10, I've clarified in the question body.

Comment: I didn't work with Ubuntu for some time, same here i expect udev/hwdb to work for you. Also because `evtest` knows the key symbol then it is may be possible to map it using `xmodmap` or `xkb`.